# Clear previous Alexa Cards

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

Is there a way to tell Alexa to either remove previous cards when I send a new one?

I have an skill which sends kind of a status each time you run a command, and typical use case is to do multiple actions in a session, each of which I'd like to send a card. It gets really cluttered since they all just add on to each other. I'd like to just either update the first card, or remove it and make a new one each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not possible with the current API. I think anyone using skills is already used to the flood of cards that come after each interaction.